# Concurrent Counter Struct with Type Argument in Rust

Tags: rust

I was following along with [this tutorial on creating a concurrent counter struct](https://www.ralfj.de/projects/rust-101/part15.html) for a `usize` value: `ConcurrentCounter`. As I understand it, this wrapper struct allows us to mutate our `usize` value, with more concise syntax, for example:`my_counter.increment(1)` vs. `my_counter.lock().unwrap().increment(1)`.

Now in this tutorial our value is of type `usize`, but what if we wanted to use a `f32`, `i32`, or `u32` value instead?

I thought that I could do this with generic type arguments:

```rust
use std::{sync::{Arc, Mutex}};

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct ConcurrentCounter<T>(Arc<Mutex<T>>);

impl<T> ConcurrentCounter<T>{
    
    pub fn new(val:T) -> Self {
        ConcurrentCounter(Arc::new(Mutex::new(val)))
    }
    pub fn increment(&self, by: T) {
        let mut counter = self.0.lock().unwrap();
        *counter = *counter + by;
    }
    pub fn decrement(&self, by: T) {
        let mut counter = self.0.lock().unwrap();
        *counter = *counter - by;
    }
    pub fn multiply(&self, by: T) {
        let mut counter = self.0.lock().unwrap();
        *counter = *counter * by;
    }
    pub fn get(&self) -> T {
        let counter = self.0.lock().unwrap();
        *counter
    }
}
```

But this yields error:

```
cannot add `T` to `T`
cannot subtract `T` from `T`
cannot multiply `T` by `T`
```

I know I need to provide some trait restrictions for my type arguments, but I'm unsure what exactly those arguments are. I know that you can't do everything you can do with an `i32` with a `f32`, but I just need to use the counter for some simple operations and it seems silly use a different wrapper struct for primitive number types.  So how would I get my `ConcurrentCounter` struct working, or is there maybe a library that provides such a counter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't come across such a `ConcurrentCounter` library, but crates.io is huge, maybe you find something. However, if you are mostly concerned with primitives such as `i32`, there is a better alternative call: [Atomics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/index.html), definitely worth checking out.

Nevertheless, your approach of generalizing the `ConcurrentCounter` is going in a good direction. In the context of operation overloading, [`std::ops`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/index.html) is worth a look. Specifically, you need `Add`, `Sub`, and `Mul`, respectively. Also, you need a `Copy` bound (alternatively, a `Clone` would also do). So you were pretty close:

```rust
use std::ops::{Add, Mul, Sub};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

pub struct ConcurrentCounter<T>(Arc<Mutex<T>>);

impl<T: Copy> ConcurrentCounter<T>{
    pub fn new(val:T) -> Self {
        ConcurrentCounter(Arc::new(Mutex::new(val)))
    }
    pub fn increment(&self, by: T) where T: Add<Output=T> {
        let mut counter = self.0.lock().unwrap();
        *counter = *counter + by;
    }
    pub fn decrement(&self, by: T) where T: Sub<Output=T> {
        let mut counter = self.0.lock().unwrap();
        *counter = *counter - by;
    }
    pub fn multiply(&self, by: T) where T: Mul<Output=T> {
        let mut counter = self.0.lock().unwrap();
        *counter = *counter * by;
    }
    pub fn get(&self) -> T {
        let counter = self.0.lock().unwrap();
        *counter
    }
}
```

Comment: you might buy yourself a little more flexibility by being generic in the argument type , i.e. `pub fn increment<S>(&self, by: S) where S: Add<Output=T>`.